# CSS select with beautifulsoup4 doesn't work

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried bs4, but the select method doesn't work.

What's wrong with my code?

```
import requests
import bs4

def main():
    r = requests.get("http://nodejs.org/download/")
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)

    selector = "div.interior:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(2) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)"
    print(soup.select(selector)[0].text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup 4 seems to have a regression from 3, where it doesn't support some selectors that it should.  For instance, `h1.a.b` doesn't match `<h1 class="a b">` for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Answer on this page differs from viewing in a browser than parsing with bs.
Have a look at your r.text and parse from there.

The response is something like

```
<div class="interior row">
<div id="installers">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.26/node-v0.10.26-x86.msi">
<img alt="" height="50" src="http://nodejs.org/images/platform-icon-win.png" width="45">
              Windows Installer
              <small>node-v0.10.26-x86.msi</small>
</img></a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.26/node-v0.10.26.pkg">
<img alt="" height="50" src="http://nodejs.org/images/platform-icon-osx.png" width="45">
              Macintosh Installer
              <small>node-v0.10.26.pkg</small>
```

so there is no table here.
Hope this helps.

Edit:
My Code is the following to get this response:

```
def main():
    r = requests.get("http://nodejs.org/download/")
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    # print r.text
    selector = "div.interior"
    print(soup.select(selector)[2])
```

Edit 2:
You could try it with find. You are mor flexible with that one.

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
print(soup.find("a", text="64-bit"))
```

Edit 3: 
This should work:

```
def main():
    r = requests.get("http://nodejs.org/download/", headers={"content-type":"text", "User-   Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5"})
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    print(soup.find("table").tr.td.findNextSibling().a['href'])
```

Comment: WTF! Is there a way to parse html like a normal browser?

Comment: edited the response. pass a header with the request and you should be fine.